# How to close user accounts from Admin API?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I want to close users (which I'm now successfully importing through Admin API) without their consent when they leave our company and their domain email gets deactivated.

I found the following methods that are related to closing users:

1. https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/reference/usermanagement/esignusermanagement/closememberships/
   This one says: "This method requires user authentication. It will fail with an application access token." So it's a no go for me because I have no way to get the user's auth form a server-side background application.
2. https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/reference/bulkoperations/userimport/closebulkuserimportrequest/
   It says "Given a CSV list of users, close their accounts."
   But the API method does not accept a CSV file as a request parameter! There is no way to pass any user data to it.
3. Maybe I could use eSignature API instead of Admin API - it has https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/users/users/delete/
   But that one says "userId string
   The ID of the user to access.
   Note: Users can only access their own information. A user, even one with Admin rights, cannot access another user's settings."

So, I'm not sure if even an Organization admin with their JWT token can use this method to delete other users? Anyway, most likely, this method will require another JWT token for eSignature API, which in turn will require more infrastructure stuff (config variables, keeping token alive) and I really would want to avoid that and stick to the Admin API only, if possible.

I'm using .net DocuSign nuget package, and I see that CreateBulkImportCloseUsersRequestAsync also has only OrganizationId as the argument. But I don't want to close all the users in the organization, I want to close them by IDs or emails, whichever is accepted by DocuSign.

How do I close user accounts properly? No matter, if it's a bulk or single-user method, as we would want to close them immediately for every separate account.

Comment: On the Users::Delete reference, the note of "Users can only access their own information. A user, even one with Admin rights, cannot access another user's settings." is a carry over from another page in documentation - it does not actually apply to that call.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot close user memberships (note that the term "account" is incorrect here) you can only disable them. You can contact support, but even they cannot really completely eliminate a user membership like it never existed. There are reasons why it must stay in a dormant state.
To explain the difference between users and accounts, here is a diagram:
[image]

Comment: Yes, I understand that I cannot remove them. I just want them to become inactive, so that they cannot log in and are not visible in search results for other company users. But there seems to be no any method to do this through Admin API - the only method that should work seems to be broken because it does not accept a CSV, although DocuSign documentation says that it should accept a CSV file.

Comment: Can you do it one by one?

Comment: Ok, I got it working with 'closeMemberships'. It's just the description is a bit misleading, it makes one think you would need the authentication of the user being deleted, while actually it is enough to have the administrator's authentication.

Comment: I can ask to fix the page and improve the documentation for this endpoint. But is there anything else you need right now?

Comment: Thank you, it's currently working well. However, it would be great if DocuSign team could also look into `closeBulkUserImportRequest` method - something seems wrong, either the method or the documentation because it is not possible to call the method with a CSV file, opposite to what the documentation claims.

Comment: Oh, and also `closeBulkUserImportRequest` documentation seems to be using wrong terminology, if, as you noted, it's a membership and not account that gets closed.

Comment: ok, I'll ask to update the documentation